Determining derivative using Ito's formula
Task
Let $B = (B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion. Express the following stochastic processes in the form
$$
dY_t = u(t, B_t) dt + v(t, B_t) dB_t,
$$
for suitable functions $u$ and $v$.
(a) $Y_t = B_t^2$
Approach
I define $f(t, x) = x^2$ so that $f(t, B_t) = B_t^2 = Y_t$. Then I am able to use following Theorem:

Theorem 4.17
Let $X$ be a one-dimensional Itô process as in (4.16) and $f \in C^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R})$. Then $f(t, X_t)$ is also an Itô process, and the following holds:
$$
df(t, X_t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(t, X_t) dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, X_t) dX_t + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(t, X_t) b_t(\omega)^2 dt.
$$

Problem
I don't know how I have to deal with the term $b_t(\omega)^2$. The term is only introduced in the following definition:

Definition 4.16
A one-dimensional Itô process is a stochastic process of the form
$$
X_t = x_0 + \int_0^t a_s(\omega) \, ds + \int_0^t b_s(\omega) \, dB_s,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are real-valued, adapted stochastic processes with the properties
$$
\mathbb{P} \left( \int_0^t |a_s(\omega)| \, ds < \infty \right) = 1 \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{P} \left( \int_0^t b_s(\omega)^2 \, ds < \infty \right) = 1, \quad \forall t \geq 0.
$$

Can somebody help me understand what I have to do with the term $b_t(\omega)^2$?.
I don't know if I gave enough information for someone to explain me how I deal with this term. If not please tell me so.

A standard Brownian motion is a special case of 4.16, with $x_0 = 0, \mathbb{P}$-a.s., $a_s(\omega) = 0$ and $b_s(\omega) = 1$.

Ok that helps me with this exercise thank you! I hope that we always use a standard brownian motion..

It does not help because $Y_t=B_t^2$ is not a martingale.

@KurtG. does this mean $b_{s}(\omega) \neq 1$? Or what are you trying to say?

$Y_t=B_t^2$ is not a martingale. By Ito, $dY_t=2B_t,dB_t+dt,.$ You should be clearer what question it is that you are asking: which Ito processes are martingales or if $Y_t$ is one of them.

I thought I clearly stated what my question is under the "Problem" section. I removed the martingale question in the task. Thank you

$b_t$ corresponds to the function $v$ in your original SDE
